# Conditional if/else statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement, assign

I am learning to improve my coding in R. I have this code:

```
data$score[testA == 1] <- testA_score
data$score[testB==1] <- testB_score
```

So basically I have four columns that I want to combine into one: testA=1 indicates if the student took version A of the test and testA_score is their score; testB=1 indicates if the student took version B of the test and testB_score is their score. I want to combine this information into new column score.

As well Suppose I had testA, testB through testH. All values are 0 or 1. How can I make new column test_complete which is = 1 if any of the tests are = 1?

Basically as a former Stata user I am looking for the R equivalent commands to egen rowtotal and egenrowfirst. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take max out of all test : since it 1 or 0 values only if at least one test is completed max will be equal to 1

```
  testA <- c(1,0, 0, 1,0,0,0)
  testB <- c(0, 1,0, 0, 1,0,1)
  testC <- c(0, 0, 0,1, 0, 1, 0)

  df <- as.data.frame(cbind(testA, testB, testC))
  df$completed <- apply(df[, 1:3], 1, max)
```

Comment: faster option is `pmax` `do.call(pmax, df[1:3])`

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, taking the maximum value by row should give what you need:

```
binary <- c(0,1)

df <- data.frame(
    score1 = sample(binary, 20, replace = TRUE),
    score2 = sample(binary, 20, replace = TRUE),
    score3 = sample(binary, 20, replace = TRUE)
)

df$passed <- apply(df, 1, max)

head(df)
```